# jQuery animation BEFORE form submission not working

Tags: php, jquery, forms, jquery-animate

When I try to add a jQuery `click` animation to my submit button it starts the animation however, quickly resets because the form submits and refreshes the page. If the form is wrapped by a `div`, the animation works fine but then the form doesn't submit after the animation is complete. How can I have it submit the form after the animation has completed and keep the animation from reseting after form-submission. I'm new to PHP and jQuery and can't figure out how to do it. Here is what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body
        {
            background-color: lightgrey;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .PSolCanvas
        {
            transform: translate(-50%, -40%);
            z-index: 1;
            position: absolute;
            left: 50%;
            top: 88.5%;
            background-color: transparent;
            min-height: 100%;
        }
        .PSol
        {
            width: 120px;
            height: 120px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
            -moz-border-radius: 100%;
            border-radius: 100%;
            font: 15px arial;
            color: black;
            border: 1px solid lightgray;
            background: #20AC20;
        }
    </style>
    <script rel = "javascript" type = "text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".PSol").click(function() {
                $(".PSolCanvas, .TSolCanvas").animate({top: "50%"});
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$username = "username";
$password = "password"; 
$host = "host";
$db = $username;

if(isset($_POST['PSol']))
{
    $connection = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $db);
    $sql = "UPDATE table SET column='' WHERE id = 1";
    if (mysqli_query($connection, $sql)) {
        echo "Record successfully changed.";
    }
    else{
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($connection);
    }
    mysqli_close($connection);
    echo "<p>Disconnected from server: ".$host."</p>";
}
?>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method = "post" class = "PSolCanvas">
        <input type = "submit" name = "PSol" class = "PSol" value = "P"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want the click animation to finish before the form submits? Is that the idea?

Comment: @Rasclatt I think so as that would allow the animation to finish, I wouldn't know how to set a delay on the submit however.

Comment: You add a callback to the animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to try doing a `callback` on the animation so the submit will happen when it's done. Something like:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".PSol").click(function(e) {
            // You will want to prevent the natural submission of the form
            e.preventDefault();
            // Notice the function attached to the `.animate()`. 
            // This will fire after the animation is done.
            $(".PSolCanvas, .TSolCanvas").animate({top: "50%"},function(){
                $('.PSolCanvas').submit();
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

---

**EDIT:** Here is an ajax version, I have made it a little complex because you may want to reuse the ajax elsewhere in your site, but you really only need the content inside the `this.ajax` part. The order of the script is important since this particular example calls itself *(calling another page for the ajax would be better)*. Everything else *(separating things into their own pages)* is just suggestion:

**/config.php**

```
<?php
// Make some defines
define("DB_USERNAME",'username');
define("DB_PASSWORD",'password');
define("DB_HOST",'host');
define("DB_DATABASE",'database');
```

**/functions/myfunctions.php**

```
<?php
// Make some functions to make things cleaner/universal
function connection()
    {
        return mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
    }
// Make a function that you can reuse
function updateTable($val,$con)
    {
        return (mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE table SET column='' WHERE id = {$val}"));
    }
```

**/index.php (whatever this page is called)**

```
<?php
// Include above assets
require_once(__DIR__.'/config.php');
require_once(__DIR__.'/functions/myfunctions.php');
// This should run only on the ajax call
if(!empty($_POST['PSol'])) {
    // Get the connection
    $con        =   connection();
    // Set common text
    $disc       =   "<p>Disconnected from server: ".DB_HOST."</p>";
    // Run the update
    if(updateTable(1,$con))
        // If success
        $response   =   json_encode(array('msg'=>"Record successfully changed. {$disc}"));
    else
        // If fail
        $response   =   json_encode(array('msg'=>"Error: {$sql}<br>".mysqli_error($con).$disc));
    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($con);
    // Stop further processing of page
    // If you don't stop processing, you will send back the rest of the 
    // page below and will malform your json
    die($response);
}
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
    body
    {
        background-color: lightgrey;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .PSolCanvas
    {
        transform: translate(-50%, -40%);
        z-index: 1;
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 88.5%;
        background-color: transparent;
        min-height: 100%;
    }
    .PSol
    {
        width: 120px;
        height: 120px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
        -moz-border-radius: 100%;
        border-radius: 100%;
        font: 15px arial;
        color: black;
        border: 1px solid lightgray;
        background: #20AC20;
    }
</style>
<script rel = "javascript" type = "text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    // This is an object to contain your ajax app
    var AjaxEngine  =   function()
        {
            // Set some common containers
            var url;
            var useURL;
            // This function will set where to point the ajax call
            this.useUrl =   function(url)
                {
                    useURL  =   url;
                    return this;
                }
            // This is the actual jQuery ajax call
            this.ajax   =   function(useData,func)
                {
                    // Create jQuery ajax
                    $.ajax({
                        // Use our previously-set url
                        url: useURL,
                        // This is the data to send to our page
                        data: useData,
                        // Send the data by POST method
                        type: 'post',
                        // When the post is successful
                        success: function(response){
                                // Use an anonymous function
                                func(response);
                            }
                    });
                }
        }

    $(".PSol").click(function(e) {
        // Set the form
        var thisForm    =   $('.PSolCanvas');
        // Get the values from the form
        var useData =   thisForm.serialize();
        // Stop from submission
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".PSolCanvas, .TSolCanvas").animate({top: "50%"},function(){
            // Create instance of our ajax object
            var Ajaxer  =   new AjaxEngine();
            // Set the url (in this case we are getting the action=""
            // from the form tag)
            // The "useData" param is the form data
            // The second param is the function we want to run when
            // the ajax successful
            Ajaxer.useUrl(thisForm.attr('action')).ajax(useData,
                function(response) {
                    // Try, just incase the code produces an error and
                    // malforms the json response 
                    try {
                        // Parse the return json_encode()
                        var json    =   JSON.parse(response);
                        // Send the message to the container
                        $('#writespot').html(json.msg);
                    }
                    catch (Exception) {
                        // This will catch any error, so
                        // make sure your console is open to review
                        console.log(Exception.message);
                        console.log(response);
                    }
                });
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- This is where the response message will be written to -->
    <div id="writespot"></div>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" class="PSolCanvas">
        <input type="submit" name="PSol" value="P" class="PSol" />
        <input type="hidden" name="PSol" value="P"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: After looking at it a bit more the animation now works but the UPDATE doesn't anymore, I dont know if you would know how to get it to work?

Comment: Like it doesn't submit the post data?

Comment: It will execute the submit on the first click but not the animation then on the second click it will move the animation upwards but not execute the submit then jump back to the starting position

Comment: So what is the series of events that should happen, step by step?

Comment: When the button is clicked it should move up the screen and stop, once stopped it should submit an update to the database. instead what is happening is the first click you make will send the update to the database then each click afterwards will move the button upwards however doesn't stop, instead moves back to the starting position. I know that without the form the animate() will move the button upwards and leave it there

Comment: Ok, you may want to then do an ajax call instead of submitting the form. When you submit the form, you start over. With ajax, you can submit and it will just sit there.

Comment: Sorry do you mean using ajax for the buttons movement or ajax to submit the update to the database?

Comment: You will use the ajax in the callback to submit the form, that way the button stays where it is and the form submits. That would change the layout of your page (just in terms of how you set up your script). If you want, I can modify my answer for that option.

Comment: Oh okay that makes sense, I've heard of ajax but never used it myself so that would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Alright take a look and see if you run into any problems.

Comment: I honestly cannot thank you enough, both for spending so much time helping me but also for helping me better understand what you've created! One final question if you dont mind, how would you set it so that there were two buttons, each changing the database individually.. I have added a 'updatetable2' in myfunctions, added a new section into the ajax (with the correct calling name),

Comment: added a new button following the same format as the original into the body and updated the top php to have a..... if(!empty($_POST['TSol'])) {...} with the updatetable2 inside however no matter which button you click on it only uses the updatetable from the above if(!empty($_POST['PSol'])) {...}... oh and the animation and database submission works perfectly by the way!

Comment: You just want the second button to call the other function?

Comment: EDIT: Ignore my previous comment I managed to get it to work, there was a PSol I failed to notice and change, Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: To do that efficiently, you will need 1) a smarter way to process the form, 2) a more robust way to process the PHP. Both are easily done, but without seeing an example, I couldn't adjust for that. Likely you only need one `updateTable()` function and then store some javascript data into the form to tell your ajax what to do.

Comment: I've now gotten it to work however I will now try and work out 1 and 2! Thanks so much for your help, this had been frustrating me for days!

Answer (score 1):

You want to submit the form after the animation has run. To do that you need to prevent the default 'submit' and then add your own using a callback function on the jQuery animate call.This will only call the .submit() after the animation has finished. Something like (Please note I haven't had a chance to check this code but it should give you the general idea:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".PSol").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(".PSolCanvas, .TSolCanvas").animate({top: "50%"},
                function() {
                $("form").submit(); 
                }
             );
        });
    });
```